# Finding Generating Function for sequence $a_n = \alpha n + \beta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

Edit: I actually found was I was missing. I forgot to use the right shift rule after deriving from $\frac{1}{1-x}$, as such my $\frac{\alpha}{(1-x)^2}$ should've been a $\frac{\alpha x}{(1-x)^2}$ for $a_n = n$

---

How to find the generating function for the sequence $a_n = \alpha n + \beta$ ?

I started by isolating $a_n = \alpha n$ and $b_n = \beta$, for which I found respectively $ \frac{\alpha}{(1-x)^2}$ and $\frac{\beta}{1-x}$

My idea was if I added them together, I should have the appropriate generating function, but apparently I'm missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's right; what are you missing?

Comment: You are right!
$$G(x)=\frac{\alpha x-\beta x+\beta}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: I guess I forgot how to do fractions, isn't $ \frac{\alpha}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{\beta}{1-x} = \frac{\alpha}{(1-x)^2}+ \frac{\beta\times(1-x)}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{\alpha+\beta-\beta x}{(1-x)^2}$ correct?